# Can I check that a plain SSL private key corresponds to an encrypted SSL private key without decrypting it?

Tags: tls, openssl, rsa

I have an AES256-encrypted file `ssl.key` and the script which sets up some software required this to be decrypted to plain text as `ssl.plain.key` as in

```
openssl rsa -in ssl.private.key -out ssl.plain.key
```

This will interactively ask for the password.

However, if the software is reconfigured there is no need to regenerate `ssl.plain.key` unless the originating `ssl.key` has changed. (For convenience's sake, I would like to not have to re-enter the password each time the settings are flushed during development.)

Can I verify that `ssl.plain.key` was derived from `ssl.private.key` without decrypting the private key again?

Comment: You can sign this key by itself (public part with private part) so this way you will know.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you use the `openssl rsa` command, I will assume that you refer to RSA private key files in the PEM format, encrypted using AES256. These look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,87FD3191BA64A020594BD81962FB092A

pqS/qSsKxhodfAafiqFyx4opaMo4HsQ9c97gT1YgI3DmZBN1w/8mlAPn8YAe98j6
...
/IlNA3RyQdHY1JIcHsnZ0HWW13kGQ1pzofhNbHQkOWimrKupKMmhPKSSMx6Q+lCm
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Unfortunately for you, all the base64-encoded data here is [encrypted](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/PEM_read_X509.html#PEM-ENCRYPTION-FORMAT) (emphasis mine):

> The line beginning with Proc-Type contains the version and the
>   protection on the encapsulated data. The line beginning DEK-Info
>   contains two comma separated values: the encryption algorithm name as
>   used by EVP_get_cipherbyname() and an initialization vector used by
>   the cipher encoded as a set of hexadecimal digits. After those two
>   lines is the **base64-encoded encrypted data**.

So it is impossible to obtain the original private RSA key without decrypting it.

Your configuration script must find other ways to detect that a RSA private key file has been updated (for example, by comparing timestamps, reading some markers, etc, etc.).

Since you mentioned SSL, note that certificates are bound to a RSA private key. In that case you can extract the public key from the RSA private key and certificate using:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -noout -modulus
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -modulus
```

Comment: It could also be 'new' (since 1999, and default for many functions since 2010) encrypted-PKCS8 format, which has `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` and not `Proc-Type` and `DEK-Info`. But if so that is also encrypted, and with a better PBE to boot.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The commonly used `openssl genrsa` utility internally uses `PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey` which always outputs the old format. As you noted, even with the new PKCS#8 format, the full contents is encrypted (convert with `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in server.key -out server.pk8`, verify with `openssl asn1parse -in server.pk8`)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the ability to determine whether encrypted content was derived from plaintext content is not good security, so without going into implementation details I'll just say this probably is not possible.

If you want to check whether an encrypted private key file has changed, I'd suggest something like the following:

At startup compare ssl.private.key with ssl.private.key.last.  If they're the same, proceed.  If they're different compute a new ssl.plain.key and overwrite ssl.private.key.last with ssl.private.key.